# CameraRoll.saveToCameraRoll "Write Busy" error when saving multiple images

Tags: react-native, camera-roll

I have a "save all" function in my React Native (for iOS) photo app that grabs the array of images and passes them to the `CameraRoll.saveToCameraRoll` function.

This is my function to save them:

```
saveAllToCameraRoll = () => {
    for (let image of this.state.downloadList) {   
        CameraRoll.saveToCameraRoll(image.uri); 
    }
};
```

`downloadList` is an array of Firebase objects referencing images stored on Firebase storage:

```
[
    -uid1234 : {
        uri: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/....",
        uploadUser: {
            ....
        }
    },
    ....
]
```

This all seems to work, and works fine for single/few images, but if downloadList gets too large (seemingly 11 images) it starts throwing a warning and some images wont get saved. The warning is:

> Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection Error: Write Busy

and also:

> Error saving cropped image: Error Domain=ALAssetsLibraryErrorDomainCode=-3301 "Write Busy"

It seems simple, that you can't save so many so quickly or it freezes up, but I can find no documentation on how to wait for it to finish one to start the next.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`CameraRoll.saveToCameraRoll` returns a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), so you can wait for it to finish with:

```
saveAllToCameraRoll = async () => {
    for (let image of this.state.downloadList) {   
        await CameraRoll.saveToCameraRoll(image.uri); 
    }
};
```

Or with [Airbnb's recommended way](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/issues/1122):

```
this.state.downloadList.reduce((prev, { uri }) =>
  prev.then(() => CameraRoll.saveToCameraRoll(uri), Promise.resolve()));
```

If you still want to execute a few of the operations in parallel, you can iterate with a step and wrap the operations in each iteration with [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).